# Decode base64 string to bitmap failed

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64

I am using this to function for encoding and decoding a bitmap for storing a photo in MySQL database. I insert the photo as a string and i want to retrive it in my project to display in an CircleImageView.

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is where i call it:

```
String fotoFromDB = studentFromDB.getFotoStringStudent();
Bitmap bitmap = StringToBitMap(fotoFromDB); //in the debbuger here says that bitmap==null
profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

String fotoFromDB = iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjEAAAOwCAIAAABAlrJqAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4        nOy9WZckx5WYee81c/dYMrMysxaCAEHsG0mAa7NJEFKv6m5pelrS0YPOzB8Y9Tyq9RNmXuZBZ/6A                                                                   ztGcOXNmXlpnRupNvVHdbIIgWSD2hUBVAShUYak9l1jc3ezeefDIKE9fIjwiPLYs+04RjIwwN7u2                                                                   XrvXFsdPPnsDHOsDIi5bhJkQkcLvy/KVhE//upolYK0dGyYtuVIKjpdGPqeLR0SGIiWSDOUpq7gy                                                                   ZszIpMmtO/dafssQEb1sGRyONWbqoWRdxqB1kdNxYnA6yeGYkpM9XosIItZlNjkcFXE6yeGYhuGg                                                                   PN3onH9q6T7JtONu+A0zDwVLf5i3Tpq0NJyOPDHQsgVwONaJzFgpR0waz9QPzonMylZ+oSv9/eqI                                                                   7ThhIKLTSQ7HlMwyRq/s+F5mwA2lXSlV6jh5ON+dwzEZGc/V1L67JJ6lu+zKSGRLizdUS5nv54Hz                                                                   3d2zODvJ4ZiVGZeUVmQ8LRQDjxgb0uGoBWcnLZmVnSZnKBuGiOY7rcmXz2LO8VSJP73mP4s8I05f                                                                   DU2TeZRz4emooRWY+OjyGxzyz+Z/nSjpQpgZJjmXNvp82+rj7MIhzk5yOJZD4TC0CmPNusyTHCcS                                                                   p5McjiUwYtxPq6XMqaBFiuQ0k2MpON+doxJuhJoHwy1t+dOp6TALMJ4yZ48Wk+gCWHef3j2I00mO                                                                   E8W66M788kzmioTFX/GXPxK7LoXpOEk4neSohBue5k2hnZQ+GzRX8vV7Ykwlx3rhdJLDsQSqXBy3                                                                   yLt80immz06tu1pyvru1w+1xcDhWi6UPl84mdiwRZyfNl7Xr3gsWuGxhf0iVczn5uwamEKAiQ3ky                                                                   iy7JeZpCkQrJhE8/mNx8CqnzqguzV/Jb/iB1Rir/U/7BdPmMSGiK+8WnW+Iqi3/dzwOVyY88mZy8                                                                   euOT00mOhbJq7qAZdXBhdiY6b1vxp3nPFUa7EKe70G/tJmSOVcDpJMeiSa/bj13Dr7LcstxNYgu4                                                                   tm5NtbhTS44pcDrpHmXpg0XmRM4U8mRU0SIH7rQeKhx5x/okR/iUCq/8mV3mGaloLeUrZTrhVyHL                                                                   jqXgdJJjoUxkJFVhWaP2iEM8M+5YGxbLaLVXL1XulZjIQoKiunY4xuJ0kmMJjLi2IMPokX12911d                                                                   d6cOyWyknjT+vDJbzLshxvpIM3scysJnDv86VeSYFKeT7lGWfm4jM65NJ09dnqLZKdz7N7XbKv0a                                                                   i7XbFVKLkbT09ulYFk4nOZbGKoy2kwpQeN9BPraxWZt0j/LSC2oWnMHkqI7TSVOyan1s0vcbzXuM                                                                   q1g+ZTsUxoo36WR8fvVV+CahtKEz+nE8fvN3/txSEoO1dhiSiIafM+8ZSlahYPL85h106XhqWfmb                                                                   iEltzXnr8knLc8T5szrEKeUEzGmcTnI46mceg3h6y0ON0S6Xsfais7HuNZxOcjhqprpPsvrIW7jx                                                                   YWjKyPEXwq6g0ppFJKeW7imcTjohuE67Csyydbv66Z9Mivnk1qgxVN9XuUaZgrWqglXD6STHTLi+                                                                   lydzorb2+MtWsIZbxlfQTpqO2c+xnYD1lXsNp5NOCE43rBQ47l0PZXsKRseZ/jOj9tK/rqD7bop9                                                                   hutrJIHThTPgdJLDUSdpq2XEYJpeCoIJFVJm9/najdcVcZdB3Js4neRw1EPh0aXF70VeQSNpBBPZ                                                                   EydYATuGOJ1UzMo2/boEm9S3MO9006lXMR3y8eRXWdJb0aYQtWK6mdQzYiil4OjYUJqy9wxRWaZL                                                                   vmcsvvVn6iskMp8zN0rkE5pI/+Vv7qhey9X3JVbJe13tf9XOPpe+D6lEnrLgS5zWuPfMOhyLZmVn                                                                   PCOYZaB3OKrjdJJjhUjfGpA2dNaawm1yJ4D13YDuWGWc786xEmROgKa/Lwu/IMnqY5bTS8sCj9/g                                                                   nv+cP7FbGM8aLXHNFVc+Y3E6yXGMJQ6X+R1Wa9RRK4416f3Nc5epJsrqJa9iF7C9YtXutXPUjtNJ                                                                   jpVjxoX61SSTqTXSSQkZIyn//UmqLMcScTrJsRLkj/VMuu8uYZXH+vXapT2aESqqMPyJyfiMuPIZ                                                                   i9vj4HAsDjxi2YJMQ+EBrKVI4jjBODtpwLJ6V9n8qOy9R8ti3nJm3gM0ZNJzMIV3HOTP1swucEXK                                                                   0krKLZM1ESk/MTKK5MwTpHReXfUydj1sWMIJY/ekjDjwVBh+dGxwfHGr4uMwm11SZQ/OpPFXP321                                                                   XE/pAhZEnU5yVGLB4/h0jrs1oqKL8gRzAirRMQ9WazLuuJcpm+qe1HMw6QymD2atERk/5Aj5x24W                                                                   dzgSnJ20ZO61Ljo2vxkDouwczLqTzk7aGzNp9hALvCgLsL2mq4gTVomOeeB00glnjfp//phL2nqo                                                                   cjBzvcjnYjpdknEA1jvoV1kvSa8xjDaVJr3vznGvISJOJy2ZdRle5y3niN0NmT/XpcRGU3r49ISO                                                                   0Ses+hzzw+kkx0IZPe/On1IqOwez7hT67qYwcRLfXXp34iL3TWRsnYqO2bI/HQ5wOslRkUnv5J+F                                                                   /FB14gevuwppfbI5ufo84ZXoqIW10UmLHBOrsGryLN63Nl34iuWW3tCVOaI0kQuocAo/yx2vefmT                                                                   Nx6VhWcsfvNR/nxPWRJjTuqwHP189P/J05aTU0pDW5OZRUSonnaSOacyrK/knFlZMDiumaawC/MV                                                                   Wqjqxiq/us4VVYm/SpxV/AfpkGPjnJP6X8B9hm4vuGPVWdPJNU4idUYH1yvJXAuwyv5vh6M6a2Mn                                                                   ORzrvpO4TO55OLUyNuXdtat6kwGAIvnXt46WxZpOvOaB00mO9SCjkCbtw3X5Wgv2B070fFFsx7e5                                                                   D36qZZAqUhV1+qbyHrnC8nQDrqM6Tic5VpqytZ+6hrkFrAuOjSitbof76KpGXh6yyrLZjOR3tOdT                                                                   dwrJMRFOJznuCeZtJxXGjwIEwBVSSO19HyVtdQqdaTXu68vs0c9v2XC77CZi1fZMLRGnkxzrwZp2                                                                   zkQt5RkqqvwgPrV/spBhzLXfNF927NcpJMcsuH13jvVjvfQTSsEePJLiqyvqzVp6pwMs48CA00yO                                                                   SdGF7XXENKesfS+r8dVl866a/EMmPYhT/ZFZkqs9/onOW+RXXDLNMm1qJKTfV5QOmX9vU/LZWosp                                                                   hlGNkD+JioiUUojIxlprFWJyTohTbzkCQgBAFk7doJq8OomKTp8gYubcT0bawu+TSJiZiDLCT3He                                                                   JUOZPAl5t17t537S9tnYRbXq+a0ynszi7510vJq63FZkfK5CplcW++7udp6REa3XdNWxjlRcw186                                                                   ieJJOg7z4LwqEQFzkgUCEABOxlBALtr/NiI/U/S1/Nb5JZbYvM+o1oUb05bOXZ00ReNwasmxRArX                                                                   M+aRUBXfV2JOMTMzG2OIiJRWSgkACoiIICCiAuAKew3m0a0W2VvTq0pzrRrHyaN0j8PoNpS2oJ1a                                                                   updZeu3nN33VFW3yoXoLH5pKzGytHexu4IFwBIiIggDMlhlpsPM7S26dqWJPzEYzcn/2pPFUD59O                                                                   2ukhxxRoPH79VMXHFjA5ddxTTOejn3c7lOM3lI8NOVg6YrbWGhZgVkgoQESoiYgSlx0zE6m7z+Zi                                                                   q3cx4NiiTk333Y1ODtwQ4ZiWrO+uSutxRpJjYYy1A/InY+pKd9gjqm8zGaolERHLxhg50kkaAL1B                                                                   RCiCAlIUa2YtfbiVYMRehjJhMr8elUw9HbaKXYUjL3fIh18F1mXd6wRzzHeXVksVt7KMDew42Sy9                                                                   D8/PR5RXSyPSGnYHRBzsuwMr1gKLWI7RMrMGUUoBQHJdN2Cx7y6d+iy5S++ym3p756Spp8thRvkd                                                                   9yYaSprsRH5kZzA55kRFw33eA9/YFp647BIxkh13FhEQOTIsli2jMBASIhIiIh8dWRJM/nfMfsm7                                                                   IibdC14YQKTQNlsE66KZ1kXOE4xO2nq6JvInOdJkJo9DP
```

The problem is that when i try to transform this code back in bitmap it doesn't work.

Comment: Have checked to see if  b = encodeByte  from `byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();`  and `byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode`

Comment: no i haven't checked.

Comment: @Barns now i get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64` on this line:  `byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(fotoDinBD, Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: @MihaelaMiki sounds like you have a base64 string that isn't formatted correctly or contains invalid characters. Try it with a base64 string you know decodes correctly.

Comment: I don't see anything with `fotoDinBD` in your code above.

Comment: @Barns `fotoDinBD` is the same variable `foroFromDB` i just forgot to translate

Comment: @Sub6Resources how to try with a base64?

Comment: I have tried your code that converts a `Bitmap` to a Base64 encoded `String` and then used your code to convert that `String` back to a `Bitmap` and your code worked flawlessly. I suggest there might be an issue with how the Base64 string is being saved to the Database. Try to compare the `String` generated by `BitMapToString` and the `String` you obtain from `studentFromDB.getFotoStringStudent();` Perhaps the column in which you store the Base64 encoded string is too small?